# Stop Emscripten from creating global "Module"

Tags: javascript, module, global, emscripten

**Is there a way to prevent emscripten from creating window scoped global "Module"?**

I generate some .js using something like `emcc --bind -O3 --memory-init-file 0 whatever...`. If I include the output script, window object gets flooded with various internal emscripten functions and objects.

I tried to wrap generated code like this:

> Some.Namespace.Whatever = (function() { ...generated code...; return Module;})();

Everything seems to work fine, but emscripten still creates window scoped global "Module" (other internal functions are gone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [this commit](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/commit/746230f45557868a91741553bf12cb17a3a95628) from February 4th this year, which I believe is part of Emscripten > v1.29.9, if the code is wrapped by some method, the Module object is not exposed on the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the pre and post js options to wrap the code in a self executing anonymous function? [0]  So he pre js would be `(function () {` and post js would be `})();`.  This could just as easily be done manually as part of a build step with Unix `cat`.

That or shove it in a worker. [1]

I don't think emscripten assigns `window.Module` or `this.Module` in emitted code, but I'm not a computer to check right now, maybe you could?

[0] https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/1c12291bcb77fac633d9fbe08c817746c4ce24c3/site/build/text/docs/tools_reference/emcc.txt#L269-L277

[1] https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/1c12291bcb77fac633d9fbe08c817746c4ce24c3/site/build/text/docs/tools_reference/emcc.txt#L468-L474